# How do I split a tuple in python

Tags: python-2.7

How do I split a tuple?

I want to split the tuple, but an error occurs.

> error :  File "", line 1, in

How do I turn this...

`a = ( '1', '2abc3', '4', '5')`

into this?

`a = ( '1', '2a', 'bc3', '4', '5')`

Comment: What is your condition for the spit?

Answer (score 0):

Tuple is immutable,
If you want to do like you mentioned you can add all elements of tuple to list and then you can do your operation and then again you can add all elements of list to tuple

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change a tuple using codes like tuple.pop() or tuple.remove() that you can use in lists.So I recommend editing your code directly.